# RCP/Plugin-Dev: How to add jar to target plattform

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, target-platform

I have an Eclipse RCP Application! And I copied the newest xtend lib (2.6.2, and xbase.lib too) to the plugin folder of the target/plattform.

But it still says that I have to copy the xtend lib to the classpath... (eclipse shows failures before running the plugin)
And I cant choose the newer version of the lib in the dependencys tab of my manifest (there was an old version of xtend in the target plattform too).

Is there something more then copying the jar files into the plugin folder to add a lib to your plugin project?

Comment: You can only have Eclipse plugins in the target platform. Is what you copied a plugin?

Comment: First I used the update site fo xtend, then I downloaded the runtime libraries .jar files and copied them into the target plattform. xtend is a plugin for eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add to a target platform from an update site you should open Preferences > Plug-in Development > Target Platform.

Click Edit... to edit the existing target platform.

On the Locations tab click Add... to add a new location.

Choose 'Software site' to add from an update site. Click Next and follow the instructions.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I tryed this but it gives me an error: Unable to locate installable unit org.eclipse.xtend.sdk.feature.group